# Running any pm2-meteor command throws Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, meteor, deployment, pm2

I have pm2-meteor installed on a CentOS 7 server which deploys meteor projects which will be managed by a reversed proxy in nginx server. I had to update Node some time ago (because of some packages dependencies) but didn't encountered any problems.

Today I accessed the server to make an update and create a new deploy with some changes and for any command (deploy, stop, start, logs...) argument for pm2-meteor I get this error:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:896:19)
```

I uninstalled NodeJs, pm2 and pm2-meteor and reinstalled NodeJs v 0.10.41, pm2 v1.0.0, and pm2-meteor v0.3.9. Still nothing is changed.

Does anyone have an idea about what can cause this error? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ps aux | grep pm2` to see if you have any pm2 instances running. Kill them using `kill -9` and then try to launch again.
PM2 loads in memory and executes from there. Perhaps you have an abandoned pm2 process that is bound to the port.

Comment: Tried that already, but nothing changed. Thx for the response.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigating time I realised that I changed the ssh port on the server and I forgot to add it in pm2-meteor.config file.
Soo don't forget the port in server tag... Just stupid...